# Database and UI framework for J2ME?

Tags: database, java-me, cdc, rms, cldc

I am an Android developer. I haven't developed J2ME applications before. I have a requirement in which the client needs a J2ME application which requires me to store around **10,000 (Each record would have around 60-150 KB of data)** records on the mobile phone. The mobile app will also be tied up with a backend server using a REST based web service.

The client wants the app to run on a specific mobile - Nokia 5233.

I need the correct options to proceed. Currently I am using the RMS and LWUIT. I chose them because:

RMS - I am using the **CLDC** profile. I am not aware of any DB that can be used with this configuration. Apache Derby is supported only in CDC.

LWUIT - There are many cases in the application where the TextField requires **event listeners**, the StringItem in LCDUI doesn't seem to have any event listeners.

Please enlighten me. I'm not sure whether I am taking the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RMS is probably your only decent option for on-device data persistence in J2ME (unless you go for direct file access using JSR-75, however if you aren't signed, the user will see all sorts of intrusive error popups when using this API).  10,000 records at 60KB per record, i.e. 614MB minimum?  I've never heard of a MIDlet storing this size of data, RMS is intended really for a meg or two at most.

Why do you need to use J2ME?  The 5233 is a Symbian^1 device, maybe try a native technology such as Qt?  Probably far more reliable for that size of data, and easier to get a nice UI too.

(By the way, what events would you expect `StringItem` to give?  It's a display-only widget.)

Comment: Oh, that Symbian breaks your brain when you try to understand a thing about it.

Comment: Pure Symbian, for sure.  But Qt/QML's pretty easy in comparison.

Comment: truth i would recommend to use JSR-75 for such size of data